# iphone 6: Making some apps not need passcode

Tags: iphone

On my iPhone6, I have set a passcode to unlock. On a locked home screen, the screen can be slid up to run some apps (e.g. flashlight, timer/clock, calculator, camera, YouTube) in the locked state. Is it possible to add some other apps to run while it is locked?

For instance, I want the phone to have a passcode to unlock, but want to let the Dictionary app to be run without requiring to enter the passcode.

Is that possible?

Comment: the short answer is no you can't.  If you can, I don't know how and I've been an iPhone user since July 11, 2008

Comment: @Buscar웃 The first picture on my camera roll (now called "all pictures") is dated July 11, 2008 at 11:42AM.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) seems to also support this date also in the right column sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of the Clock, Camera, and Calculator apps (which can be opened in Action Center (if you have it enabled in the lock screen)), there is no way to open any app without a passcode.

There is limited functionality with push notifications (but only on certain conditions, like, say, a tweet pops up in the lock screen and you can either retweet or favourite the tweet) and in Notification Center (if enabled in the lock screen), but that depends on whether or not the app has support for either one.